# image_tag - Is there a way to make the alt attr blank by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, alt

I rather have a blank alt attribute if an image is missing instead of the filename of the image (who ever wants this default behavior anyway?)

Is there a way to make a system configuration so image_tag sets a blank alt attr if no alt was given?

Just to be clear: I am not interested in image_tag('path/to/image', :alt => '') I am interested in setting it once for all the image_tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Rails 3.2 add this under config/initializers

```
module ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper

  def image_alt(src)
    return ''
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can monkey-patch [`ActionView::Helper#image_alt`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e826a5c749f9a4029a3b2a7e3d371498feeb9b10/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb#L377) with:

```
def image_alt(src)
  ''
end
```

Comment: I think it needs to be ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper#image_alt(src)

Comment: I just verified that patching ActionView::Helper will not work for Rails 3.2. Please update your answer with my previous comment and I will up vote and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Or use your own version of image helper

```
#ApplicationHelper
def my_image_tag(source, options={})
  options(:alt) = ''
  image_tag(source, options)
end
```

Then use it, `my_image_tag "test/test.png"`