# how to show nothing instead of missing image in paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip to upload my photos. If a photo is not uploaded it shows missing image which is not tidy instead, I want to render nothing in place of that missing image.

```
this is my index.html.erb  view

<tbody>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= product.title %></td>
        <td><%= product.dscription %></td>

         <% if product.photo.nil?%>
         render 'nil'
          <% else %>
          <td><%=image_tag product.photo.url(:thumb) %></td>
          <% end %>
         <% if product.photo1.nil?%>
          <td><%=image_tag nil %></td>
          <% else %>
          <td><%=image_tag product.photo1.url(:thumb) %></td>
          <% end %>
```

Comment: You should use the alt option in the image_tag - <%= image_tag product.photo, :alt => "LOL No image" %> to display something else if no image is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this in your code to get an alternate text of your choosing:

```
 <%= image_tag product.photo.url(:thumb)%>
```

As you want nothing if the image is not there. do something like this:

Add this under `config/initializers`

```
module ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
  def image_alt(src)
    return ''
  end
end
```

Same has been asked [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115771/image-tag-is-there-a-way-to-make-the-alt-attr-blank-by-default). 
Please search properly before asking any question.

Comment: but i dont want to display anything if image is not presenet