# Empty alt with Rails image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, helper

I have a number of images that need an empty alt attribute, that is `alt=""`, using `image_tag`.

I tried the code in the accepted answer at [image_tag - Is there a way to make the alt attr blank by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115771/image-tag-is-there-a-way-to-make-the-alt-attr-blank-by-default) but it results in `<img alt>` not `<img alt="">`.

Short of removing `image_tag` and using `img` can this be done?

Comment: `<%= image_tag src, alt: 'some_alt' %>` doesn't work?

Comment: It needs to be the empty string. Literally `alt=""` in the HTML.

Comment: How are you checking the alt attribute? With Chorme developer tools??

Answer (score 2):

Ok this is a non-issue. Alejandro's comment on the original question prompted me to check the source, I had previously only checked in devtools inspector.

The source is `alt=""` using  the linked code, it's `alt` in Chrome's DOM.

Thanks for suggestions, sorry for any trouble.